# Spring Security and Google Contacts API integration throwing exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-contacts-api

My use case is to retrieve google's contacts for a user and for that I was following https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login#google-login tutorial along with Google Contacts API docs - https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3

I am using Spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE and Spring security 5.3.2.RELEASE. I am able to authenticate and authorize user without giving any scope but as soon as I add `scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` in `application.yml`, its throwing `Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/plain]` exception.

`application.yml`

```
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <<client-id>>
            client-secret: <<client-secret>>
            scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
        provider:
          google:
            user-info-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly?alt=json
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/plain]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:110) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/plain]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:123) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:998) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:981) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:110) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
```

I also tried not giving scope in `application.yml` so that I can get successful authentication and then try calling `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full` by passing the right authorization token in `Authorization` header but I got `403 Forbidden` because the initial authorization dint have enough scope.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full")
                .queryParam("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly")
                .queryParam("alt", "json");
restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.toUriString(), String.class )
```

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
]
```

Comment: I suspect you don't need to add the full URL to the list of scopes. Try setting `scope: contacts.readonly`

Comment: If I do that I get following error -
```Error 400: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[contacts.readonly]}```

Comment: The scopes are mentioned over here - https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3

Comment: My apologies, you are correct about the scope. Have you tried it without setting the `user-infor-uri`, or setting it to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`?